# Erro ao passar valores para @Html.DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdown

Meu *Controller*:

```
  public ActionResult AssociarDependencia(int codigoMilestone, int codigoAtividade)
    {
        try
        {
            using (CPMDatabaseEntities db = new CPMDatabaseEntities())
            {
                List<Atividade> lista = new List<Atividade>();
                lista = db.Atividade.Where(a => a.CodigoMilestone == codigoMilestone).ToList();
                ViewBag.Atividades = lista;
                return View();

            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Minha *View*:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Atividade Sucessora", new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Atividades")
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Usando o debug esse executa normal, vemos na imagem abaixo que o código retorna 2 valores.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando o debug chega no `@Html.DropDownList("Atividades")` ele dá uma exceção como vemos nas imagens abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer retornar com alguma atividade já selecionada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Html.DropDownList` não tem como adivinhar o que tem na sua `ViewBag`. Você tem que informar isso a ela em código.

Para o seu caso, a seguinte construção é a mais recomendada:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AtividadeId, ((IEnumerable<Atividade>)ViewBag.Atividades).Select(option => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = option.Nome,
            Value = option.AtividadeId,
            Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.AtividadeId == option.AtividadeId)
        }), "Selecione...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está passando um `List<Atividade>` ao invés de um `List<SelectListItem>`.

Tenta fazer isso:

```
    public ActionResult AssociarDependencia(int codigoMilestone, int codigoAtividade)
    {
        try {
            using (CPMDatabaseEntities db = new CPMDatabaseEntities()) {
                List<Atividade> lista = new List<Atividade>();
                lista = db.Atividade.Where(a => a.CodigoMilestone == codigoMilestone).ToList();

                IList<SelectListItem> listItens = new List<SelectListItem>();

                foreach (var item in lista) {
                    listItens.Add(new SelectListItem {
                        Text = lista.Propriedade,   // Valor que será o Texto do Dropdown
                        Value = lista.Propriedade,  // Valor que será o Value do Dropdown
                        Selected = false            // Indica se o item será selecionado por padrão no Dropdown
                    });
                }

                ViewBag.Atividades = listItens;
                return View();

            }

        }
        catch (Exception) {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

E na sua View, faça o seguinte:

```
        <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Atividade Sucessora", new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Atividades",(IList<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listItens)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Eu tenho uma extensão que criei para converter uma coleção genérica em uma coleção de SelectListItem, vou pega-la e posto aqui mais tarde, mas por enquanto esse código deve te ajudar.